# Need to get data from multiple tables with same foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

- table-1 with `InjID` (PK) and `Name`
- Table 2 with `Tid` (RefK) refers to `InjId` (Table1) and `Name`
- Table 3 with `ID` (RefK) refers to `InjID` (Table1) and `Name`

There is no link between Table 2 and Table 3.

I have data like this:

Table1

```
________________
InjID     Name
----------------
1         xxxx
2         bbbb
3         cccc
4         yyyy
```

Table 2

```
--------------
TID      Name
--------------
1        A3434
1        R5678
2        G6789
```

and Table 3

```
-------------
ID     Name
-------------
2      89T
2      78P
3      66J
```

I want the results like this:

```
--------------------------
injid    Table1-name Table2-name table3-name
--------------------------------------------
1         xxxx        A3434        null
1         xxxx        R5678        null 
2         bbbb        G6789        89T
2         bbbb        null         78P
3         cccc        null         66J
4         yyyy        null         null
```

Comment: What sort of SQL is it? i.e. Oracle? SQL Server? You can usually create a view with one of their GUIs and work it out from there.

Comment: Its Sql server and I want a normal SQL query to generate the report in Microstrategy

Comment: Should be sufficient to do `FROM Table_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_2 on Table_1.Name = Table_2.Name LEFT OUTER JOIN ...`

Comment: i tried that its giving cartesian product

Answer (score 2):

I guess you simply want an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
select t1.injid, t1.name, t2.name, t3.name
from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t1.InjID = t2.tid
  left join table3 t3 on t1.InjID = t3.id
```

Executes like:

```
SQL>select * from table1;
      InjID name
=========== ==========
          1 xxxx
          2 bbbb
          3 cccc
          4 yyyy

                  4 rows found

SQL>select * from table2;
        TID name
=========== ==========
          1 A3434
          1 R5678
          2 G6789

                  3 rows found

SQL>select * from table3;
         ID name
=========== ==========
          2 89T
          2 78P
          3 66J

                  3 rows found

SQL>select t1.injid, t1.name, t2.name, t3.name
SQL&from table1 t1
SQL&  left join table2 t2 on t1.InjID = t2.tid
SQL&  left join table3 t3 on t1.InjID = t3.id;
      InjID name       name       name
=========== ========== ========== ==========
          1 xxxx       A3434      -
          1 xxxx       R5678      -
          2 bbbb       G6789      89T
          2 bbbb       G6789      78P
          3 cccc       -          66J
          4 yyyy       -          -

                  6 rows found
```

With nulls. Good enough?

Comment: i don't want to get cartesian product. the forest i used the same but i am not looking for this output. pls see my output above.

Comment: if i use left joins the table 2 and table 3 names are giving cartesian product. i want nulls

Comment: Added output. Any comments?